# wav_to_audio custom function is not working

Tags: matlab, audio, wav

At my wit's end. This program used to work for me, but now for some reason I keep getting that I cannot open the file. (Was using the same file before and no problem). I tried to just switch to wavread only and it worked but it added all sorts of complications for me to debug throughout the rest of my program, so I'd really like to get wav_to_audio working again.

The error message is

> Error using wavread (line 70) Invalid Wave File. Reason: Cannot open file.
>
> Error in wav_to_audio (line 108) [f_audio,fs,nbits] = wavread(strcat(dirAbs,dirRel,wavfilename));
>
> Error in test_TempogramToolbox (line 61) [audio,sideinfo] = wav_to_audio('',dirWav,filename);

Here is the matlab code:

```
clear close all

dirWav = 'data_wav/';

filename = 'Debussy_SonataViolinPianoGMinor-02_111_20080519-SMD-ss135-189.wav';
% filename = '110-130bpm_click.wav';
% filename = 'Faure_Op015-01_126_20100612-SMD-0-12.wav';
% filename = 'Poulenc_Valse_114_20100518-SMD-0-15.wav';
% filename = 'Schumann_Op015-03_113_20080115-SMD-0-13.wav';

%% load wav file, automatically converted to Fs = 22050 and mono
[audio,sideinfo] = wav_to_audio('',dirWav,filename); Fs = sideinfo.wav.fs;

%% wav_to_audio function
if parameter.message == 1
    fprintf('wav_to_audio: processing %s, ',wavfilename);
end

[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(wavfilename);
if strcmp(ext,'.wav')
    [f_audio,fs,nbits] = wavread(strcat(dirAbs,dirRel,wavfilename));
else
    error(['Unknown file format ' ext]);
end

bConverted_to_mono = 0;
if parameter.convertToMono
    if size(f_audio,2)>1
        bConverted_to_mono = 1;
        if parameter.message == 1
            fprintf('converting to mono, ');
        end
        switch parameter.monoConvertMode
            case 'leftmost_channel'
              f_audio= f_audio(:,1);
            case 'rightmost_channel'
              f_audio= f_audio(:,size(f_audio,2));
            case 'downmix' % pay attention to energy loss due to differences in phase
                           % when using this method. This is often the case for bad
                           % stereo mixes
              nChannels = size(f_audio,2);
              f_audio = sum(f_audio,2);
              f_audio = f_audio / nChannels;
            otherwise
              disp('wav_to_audio: monoConvertMode : Unknown method')
        end
    end
end
bResampled = 0;
if parameter.useResampling
    if (fs ~= parameter.destSamplerate)
        bResampled = 1;
        if parameter.message == 1
            fprintf('Resampling to %d, ', parameter.destSamplerate);
        end
        f_audio = resample (f_audio,parameter.destSamplerate,fs,100);
        fs = parameter.destSamplerate;
    end
end

%% Update sideinfo
sideinfo.wav.version = 1;
sideinfo.wav.filename = wavfilename;
sideinfo.wav.dirRel = dirRel;
sideinfo.wav.size = size(f_audio,1);
sideinfo.wav.duration = (sideinfo.wav.size-1)/fs;
sideinfo.wav.energy = sum(f_audio.^2);
sideinfo.wav.fs = fs;
sideinfo.wav.nbits = nbits;
sideinfo.wav.channels = size(f_audio,2);
sideinfo.wav.resampled = bResampled;
sideinfo.wav.monoConverted = bConverted_to_mono;
if bConverted_to_mono
    sideinfo.wav.monoConvertMode = parameter.monoConvertMode;
else
    sideinfo.wav.monoConvertMode = 'none';
end

%% Saving data
if parameter.save == 1
    if parameter.message == 1
        fprintf('Saving to file, ');
    end
    filename = strcat(parameter.saveFilename,'_audio');
    save(strcat(parameter.saveDir,filename),'f_audio','sideinfo');
end
if parameter.message == 1
    fprintf('Done\n');
end

%% Visualization
if parameter.vis
    figure;
    for k=1:sideinfo.wav.channels
        if sideinfo.wav.channels > 1
            subplot(sideinfo.wav.channels,1,k);
        end
        plot( [0:sideinfo.wav.size-1] / sideinfo.wav.fs , f_audio(:,k));
        axis tight;
    end
end

end
```

Comment: What program is this? One that you wrote, or an internal proprietary program at your company, or a common open source program? What language is the program in.

Comment: Apologies. It is in MATLAB, and it is a function built into Müller and Grosche's tempogram toolbox. I did not write it myself, hence half the issues.